# datatables bootstrap pagination - only show previous / next

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

Been integrating the jquery DataTables plugin to my rails app, via the rweng/jquery-datatables-rails gem.  It's awesome.  I even went so far as to style it with bootstrap.

So, I have bootstrap, and kaminari for pagination (not sure if that matters).  There is a kaminari-bootstrap gem as well.

Anyway, the DataTables table shows previous 1 2 3 4 5 next, and it's just chunky.  How can I lose the numbers, and just have previoius next?

currently calling datatable with:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#companyBoxList').dataTable
    sDom: "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
    sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
    bJQueryUI: true
    bProcessing: true
    bServerSide: true
    sAjaxSource: $('#companyBoxList').data('source')
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have 6 options:

- `numbers` - Page number buttons only
- `simple` - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons only
- `simple_numbers` - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons, plus page numbers
- `full` - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons
- `full_numbers` - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers
- `first_last_numbers` - 'First' and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers

The `numbers` and `first_last_numbers` options were recently added.

*(src: http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)*

---

So in your case :

```
// Code jQuery.
$('#companyBoxList').dataTable({
  pagingType: "simple"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that this answer referred to an older version of DataTables. There are now six [pagination options](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType):

> **numbers** - Page number buttons only (1.10.8) 
>   **simple** - 'Previous' and
>   'Next' buttons only 
>   **simple_numbers** - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons,
>   plus page numbers 
>   **full** - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last'
>   buttons 
>   **full_numbers** - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons,
>   plus page numbers 
>   **first_last_numbers** - 'First' and 'Last' buttons,
>   plus page numbers

---

http://www.datatables.net/usage/options

> **sPaginationType**
>
> DataTables features two different built-in pagination interaction
>   methods ('twobutton' or 'fullnumbers') which present different page
>   controls to the end user. Further methods can be added using the API
>   (see below).

Update: Apparently the Bootstrap plugin forces its own pagination layout. You could do this instead:

```
#my_table .pagination li {display: none;}
#my_table .pagination li.prev, #my_table .pagination li.next {display: inline;}
```