# Js DataTables paging not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, mobile, datatables

I'm working on a mobile app with apache Cordova and decided to display some data with DataTables plugin+bootsrap. Everything worked really well and the table looks great on mobile screen except for one little annoying thing.
I have pagination with numbers on my table.

```
    "pagingType": "simple_numbers"
```

and this produced this result:
[image]

the pesky 'Next' button jumps to next row and makes the design look broken.
Also I noticed that no matter how wide i stretch the preview screen the structure of page numbers always stays the same:

```
[previous][1,2,3,4,5,..,<last>][next]
```

What I want is to automatically adjust intermediate page number button count so that 'Next' would always fit on the same line with 'previous'

Comment: These may be of help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438307/datatables-bootstrap-pagination-only-show-previous-next
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955336/datatables-pagination-buttons-remove-unwanted-space

Comment: sadly no, these do not adress this particular problem.

Comment: You are doing more than that.  Please show how you initialise the table  (complete code) and additional custom CSS (if any) ..Also, what specific device are we talking about here? (if any)